# How to turn off a TE Redstone Energy Cell if there is no load?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-thermal-expansion

A Redstone Energy Cell (from Thermal Expansion) continuously emits energy according to the rate set in its GUI as long as it contains MJ.  If the Buildcraft machines connected to the energy network aren't doing anything, eventually the first conductive pipe connected to the Cell will explode. By comparison, an IndustrialCraft MFE stops emitting EU until a machine connected to it needs EU, and this makes it very easy to use without problems. I'd like to set up my BC power network to be as well-behaved as my IC power network.

I was able to get an Autarchic Gate to toggle the cell on/off using the 'Inventory is Full' setting when beside a machine, but this would require a Gate beside every machine connected to the power network.  I would rather use a single gate to turn the cell on or off if *any* machine connected to the cable is working, like a 'Load Connected' setting for the gate. How can I do that?

Comment: Aren't Redstone Energy Cells from Thermal Expansion, not Buildcraft?

Comment: ...and actually, somehow I overlooked the first line...MFEs are IndustrialCraft.  It might be easier to answer this question if we had some idea exactly what mods you have available (is this a Tekkit or Feed the Beast pack?)

Comment: Honestly, my solution is to use a lever. I turn the thing on when I want to use my machines, and off again when I'm done.

Comment: Most Buildcraft related machines request power as-needed. There are some that do request power all the time. Do you happen to have a Thermionic Fabricator on the power line? That one in particular uses power all the time.

Comment: @Unionhawk Machines don't request energy, they simply drain it from nearby sources. Pipes do the same. As a result, pipes will draw energy even if they have nowhere to send it, and (as of BC 3.x) will explode when overloaded. Putting the cell beside the machine behaves better, because there are no pipes involved.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the Cell is meant to be used with Redstone Energy Conduits - you'll blow up your pipes in a second with power pipes. I can tell you for certain that my power setup with an Energy Cell, Energy Conduits, and Thermal Expansion machines frequently fills up the cell, and stays static with no work. The Carpenter, Squeezer, Rolling Machine, and Assembly Lasers also do not cause a power drain. The Thermionic Fabricator does, however.

Comment: @Unionhawk I know it is, but that's not what the OP is doing. TE conduits, machines, and engines are programmed to be smart exactly because BC ones aren't, and that's why the correct answer is "use conduit" and asking about what machines are connected is missing the problem. BC machines and conductive pipe (as in this question) are by-design dumb in this way—the devs consider it a feature that adds more challenge, and the recent addition of exploding pipes is more of that same "feature."

Answer (score 3):

Use the Redstone Conduits from the same mod, since they're smart enough to stop the Energy Cell if no energy is requested by machines that they're connected to directly. (The recipe involves filling empty conduit with molten redstone in the Liquid Transposer, like the Cell's recipe.)

You'll need a Crescent Hammer to set the Conduit to get the energy from the Cell (turn the connection orange).

Comment: Now conduits are no longer part of TE, they are part of Thermal Dynamics

Comment: and there is no difference between in and out on the duct anymore

Comment: Just saying so edit the answer